# How to remove scroll from the iframe and set the height & width according to content

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]I have to work on a project and I am facing a problem of not removing the scroll from the iframe. actually, I am trying to pass several pages in a single iframe. So the iframe height is not set according to the content.

I tried a lot of javascript code but none of them works.

Comment: Please post minimal demo

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add your code into snippet so we can trying to help you.

Comment: Hello Rahul,

By your Question I can assume that you are working on a iframe from Cross origin.
Check this out
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe

Comment: In the iframe, use a bit of JavaScript that informs the parent window of the height of the document. Then let the parent window resize the iframe.

Comment: I have 21 webpages and I am targetting them to the same frame so it's really difficult to understand where to run the script.

Answer (score 1):

```
<iframe src = "" scrolling = "no"></iframe>
<style> 
iframe{
  overflow: hidden;
  }
</style>
```

Try this, it should disable the scrolling in iframes